# Where should I ask a question about the name of an algorithm?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, site-recommendation, scope

I need to know the English name of an algorithm. I can describe the algorithm in details and I also know the name of the algorithm in my mother tongue, but I don't know how to translate that name in English. In my experience direct translation from local language to English does not always work for algorithm names. Google was not very helpful here either.

I wonder if it is OK to ask such questions on Stack Overflow, or if there is another site more suited for this kind of questions. As the question is quite technical (I will have to describe the algorithm), I don't think English language & usage will do in my case.

Comment: I don't think it will be very welcome on Stack Overflow. Honestly, can't think of any Stack Exchange site where it really fits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Might be on-topic on [Computer Science](https://cs.stackexchange.com/), but check their FAQ first.

Answer (score -3):

Why not try the [Theoretical Computer Science](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/) site ?

Comment: You are advising this because you know it to be on-topic?

Comment: Arrgh, there is no *forum* on SE.

Comment: That's for "research-level questions and answers in theoretical computer science."

Comment: I see (as a side note, it seems not possible to straightforwardly consult a site's FAQ from the StackExchange Android app)